# Attack all links with an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dom-events, httpwebrequest

I've been trying create a pure function without jQuery or any other libraries to transform all links on  my web app in an ajax request. But as you should know without success.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
function ajaxify() {
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
var links = document.body.querySelectorAll('a');
[].forEach.call(links, function (link) {
    console.log(link);
    link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var url = link.href;
        // Manipulate history
        window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.onload = function () {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                content[0].innerHTML = request.responseText;
            } else {
                alert('Request failed. Returned status of' + request.status);
            }
        };
        request.send();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

}

**Edit**

One of pages that above script does not works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/authentication.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Web APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="conteiner">
            <a href="index.html"><i class="material-icons custom-arrow-back">arrow_back</i></a>
            <img class="logomarca" src="img/logo.png">
            <form name="form" id="form" action="ForgotPassword" method="POST">
                <div class="align-form">
                    <div class="input-conteiner">
                        <input class="btn-material-style" type="email" id="email" name="email"  maxlength="37" value="" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="input-subscribe feedback"></p>
                    <div class="input-subscribe" style="margin-top: 2.4em">
                        <input class="btn-material-style" id="btn-submit-email" type="submit" name="submit" value="Request new password" style="border: 0">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p><span id="copyleft">©</span> 2016 - <span class="custom-color">Web APP</span></p>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/authentication.js"></script>
        ajaxify();
    </script>
</body>
```

**Solved**

The only problem is XMLHttpRequest does not let send script as DOM text for security reasons. So I gave up and now I'm using jQuery to do that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), in order to add an event listening onto each HTMLElement within the NodeList you'll need to convert the NodeList to an array and loop through it:

```
 var links= content[0].querySelectorAll('a');

 [].forEach.call(links, function(link) {
   link.addEventListener('click', function(event) { //code });
 });
```

Also, have you tried this:

```
 document.body.querySelectorAll('a');
```

Comment: Thanks, the first snippet code works for me but now I have other problem, when I into in a page and  use the link to back it makes a normal request.

Comment: It's large the whole code. Basically, for now I have three pages, the first one has two links and the function works fine for it. But when I into in one of two links has only one link in the whole page that back to first one. But the ajax request does not seem to work when I have only one navigation link in the page.

Comment: If you're still using `content[0]` and the links aren't in the body's first child element, perhaps it isn't finding them.  Try switching to `document.body.querySelectorAll('a');`

Comment: You're right, I change that. But still does not work.

Comment: authentication.js has only ajaxify() function. And it seems that script works if page is reload after ajax request.

Comment: I will set your answer as correct because I discovered that spec XMLHttpRequest does not let send script as DOM text for security reasons. Thanks for help!

Comment: Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll('a')` will return an array of anchors. You need to iterate over that and then `addEventListener` to each one.